# Social network - Suggested friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two simple MySQL tables: user & relations.

Relations table:

```
user_id int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     
friend_id   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI
```

(part of) User table:

```
id  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     
username    varchar(128)    NO
```

I select friend of friends using this query:

```
SELECT f2.friend_id, u.username
FROM relations f1
JOIN relations f2 ON f1.friend_id=f2.user_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = f2.friend_id
WHERE f2.friend_id NOT IN (select friend_id from relations where user_id=@user_id) AND f1.user_id= 2 AND f2.friend_id!= 2
```

But I also need to get suggested friends... (people in the group who know 2 or more direct friends), and I have problems with this. What is a good way (query, or should I do it with PHP?) to get suggested friends?

Comment: No. Do it with MySQL. How do you handle reciprocity?

Comment: Whell.. I don't... Any suggestions how can I modify this query to check, if I'm also a friend of my friend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following... this example assumes that reciprocation is established by the insertion of two rows per friendship. However, for simplicity, the examples that follow do not check that friendships are reciprocated!

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends;

 CREATE TABLE friends
 (initiator VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,reciprocator VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY (initiator,reciprocator)
 );

 INSERT INTO friends VALUES 
 ('Adam','Ed'),
 ('Ed','Adam'),
 ('Adam','Ben'),
 ('Ben','Adam'),
 ('Adam','Charlie'),
 ('Charlie','Adam'),
 ('Adam','Dan'),
 ('Dan','Adam'),
 ('Ed','Ben'),
 ('Ben','Ed'),
 ('Ben','Charlie'),
 ('Charlie','Ben'),
 ('Charlie','Dan'),
 ('Dan','Charlie'),
 ('Dan','Fred'),
      ('Fred','Dan'),
 ('Adam','Fred'),
      ('Fred','Adam');
```

To get a list of all of Ben's "friends-of-friends" we can do this...

```
 SELECT y.reciprocator
   FROM friends x
   JOIN friends y
     ON y.initiator = x.reciprocator
    AND y.reciprocator <> x.initiator
   LEFT
   JOIN friends z
     ON z.reciprocator = y.reciprocator 
    AND z.initiator = x.initiator
  WHERE x.initiator = 'Ben'
    AND z.initiator IS NULL;
 +--------------+
 | reciprocator |
 +--------------+
 | Dan          |
 | Fred         |
 | Dan          |
 +--------------+
```

As you can see, because Dan is friends with both Adam and Charlie (both friends of Ben) his name appears twice.

So, to get a list of DISTINCT friends-of-friends, just include the DISTINCT operator.

Likewise, to get a list of individuals who are strangers to Ben, but friends of at least two of Ben's friends, we can do this...

```
SELECT y.reciprocator
  FROM friends x
  LEFT
  JOIN friends y
    ON y.initiator = x.reciprocator
   AND y.reciprocator <> x.initiator
  LEFT
  JOIN friends z
    ON z.reciprocator = y.reciprocator
   AND z.initiator = x.initiator
 WHERE x.initiator = 'Ben'
   AND z.initiator IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY y.reciprocator
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
 +--------------+
 | reciprocator |
 +--------------+
 | Dan          |
 +--------------+
```

There are probably several ways of dealing with the reciprocation aspect of this problem, just as there are several ways of handling reciprocity itself.

One way is to substitute each occurrence of the `friends` table above with a simple subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT y.reciprocator
  FROM (SELECT a.* FROM friends a JOIN friends b ON b.reciprocator = a.initiator AND b.initiator = a.reciprocator) x

  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT a.* FROM friends a JOIN friends b ON b.reciprocator = a.initiator AND b.initiator = a.reciprocator) y
    ON y.initiator = x.reciprocator
   AND y.reciprocator <> x.initiator

  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT a.* FROM friends a JOIN friends b ON b.reciprocator = a.initiator AND b.initiator = a.reciprocator) z
    ON z.reciprocator = y.reciprocator
   AND z.initiator = x.initiator

 WHERE x.initiator = 'Ben'
   AND z.initiator IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY y.reciprocator
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Strawberry, too bad I couldn't use your solution right off the bat... My design (oxwall) is quite different:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| userId       | friendId     | status       | whatever     | 
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1            | 3            | request      | Dan          |
| 3            | 6            | active       | 
| 1            | 7            | ignore
+--------------+
```

No dup 1->2  then 2->1 like

So my query :

```
    SELECT
        y.friendId,
        COUNT(*) AS totalFriends
    FROM
        `ow_friends_friendship` x
    LEFT JOIN `ow_friends_friendship` y 
                ON y.userId = x.friendId         

    WHERE
        x.userId = xxx
    AND  y.friendId not in (SELECT userId FROM ow_friends_friendship WHERE friendId = xxx)
    AND  y.friendId not in (SELECT friendId  FROM ow_friends_friendship WHERE userId = xxx)

    GROUP BY
        y.friendId
    HAVING
        totalFriends >= 2
    ORDER BY
        totalFriends DESC
```

Hope it may help someone in the future